# Remove text before an array of subtexts

Tags: r, regex, substring, str-replace, gsub

I have a set of strings I need to manipulate. Of each, in case they include a set of substrings,  I want to keep the substring, otherwise leave it untouched.

Here follows an example:

```
keep <- c("USA","UNITED STATES")
keep <- paste0(paste0(" ",keep,"$"),collapse="|")

data <- c("DETROIT","DETROIT USA","DETROIT UNITED STATES")
expected_result <- c("DETROIT","USA","UNITED STATES")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```r
data <- c("DETROIT","DETROIT USA","DETROIT UNITED STATES")
keep <- c("USA","UNITED STATES")

regex <- paste0(".*\\s*\\b(",paste0(keep,collapse="|"), ")\\b")
sub(regex, "\\1", data)
## => [1] "DETROIT"       "USA"           "UNITED STATES"
```

See the [R demo online](https://ideone.com/fUEmBc).

The regex is `.*\s*\b(USA|UNITED STATES)\b`, see [its online demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZpYFxU/1/).

*Details*:

- `.*` - any zero or more chars as many as possible
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `\b(USA|UNITED STATES)\b` - a whole word `USA` or `UNITED STATES`, captured into Group 1 (`\1` in the replacement pattern).

Answer (score 1):

You could use `str_extract` to extract the pattern if present. This returns `NA` in case the pattern is missing which you can replace with original `data`.

```
keep <- c("USA","UNITED STATES")
keep <- paste0(paste0(" ",keep,"$"),collapse="|")

result <- stringr::str_extract(data, keep)
result[is.na(result)] <- data[is.na(result)]
trimws(result)
#[1] "DETROIT"       "USA"           "UNITED STATES"
```